# How to force absolute element to be on top of everything else if wrapper element has overflow:hidden

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a custom select element but the problem is that when I open it, the options are cut by the upper wrapper that contains the select and I don't know how to solve it. I have managed to partially fix this by making options have fixed position but I don't like the approach. Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/kind-wind-ffdj6g?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00063b6frafu5qpo%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00023b6fkcot3weo%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00033b6f2jv80v8o%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00053b6fkx5xsk1u%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt4n9vva00023b6fkcot3weo%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00013b6fd0q7iwxu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00023b6fkcot3weo%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00013b6fd0q7iwxu%2522%257D%252C%2522clt4n9vva00053b6fkx5xsk1u%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00043b6fgxa7tjci%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00053b6fkx5xsk1u%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00043b6fgxa7tjci%2522%257D%252C%2522clt4n9vva00033b6f2jv80v8o%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00033b6f2jv80v8o%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) example I made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [React Portals](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) to render the dropdown in an overlay outside the div that would clip it.

Say, you have a component that boils down to

```html
<>
  <div className="content">
    <overlayContext.Provider value={overlayRef}>
      {props.children}
    </overlayContext.Provider>
  </div>
  <div ref={overlayRef} className="overlay" />
</>
```

then you can wrap your whole app in a context provider that provides a ref to an overlay div to anywhere you need it. Then you can render dropdowns and other widgets into that element via `React.createPortal(<...>, overlayRef.current)`

In this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/romantic-wozniak-q56qlf?file=%2Fsrc%2FSelection.tsx%3A23%2C50&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00063b6frafu5qpo%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00023b6fkcot3weo%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00033b6f2jv80v8o%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00053b6fkx5xsk1u%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt4n9vva00023b6fkcot3weo%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00023b6fkcot3weo%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt5tais00002356hfkmcbflr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A23%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A50%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A23%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A50%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FSelection.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt5tais00002356hfkmcbflr%2522%257D%252C%2522clt4n9vva00053b6fkx5xsk1u%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00043b6fgxa7tjci%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00053b6fkx5xsk1u%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00043b6fgxa7tjci%2522%257D%252C%2522clt4n9vva00033b6f2jv80v8o%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4n9vva00033b6f2jv80v8o%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) I went a step further and added a component `Anchored` that removes the need to manually calculate the absolute positions of elements rendered into that overlay div (since they're no longer positioned relative to the original parent).