How to dynamically position an element above another div without knowing the height?
I would like to open up a portaled overlay (calendar) above, and to the right of, an input element.
This works, but the problem is that I'm indicating top: -700px. However in actuality, I don't know this height. How can I get this to work?
Initially I tried using getComputedStyle or getBoundingClientRects, and rendering the overlay only once the height is determined (using a second "ghost" component with 0 opacity), however this approach hurts the UX. Another idea I had was to get the coordinates of the top-right corner of the input and then just set the position that way.
Here is what I have:
.root {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.innerContainer {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 12px;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: tomato;
  right: 0;
  top: -700px;
}

import * as React from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import "./App.css";

function Overlay() {
  const [node, setNode] = React.useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const node = document.querySelector(".input");

    if (node) {
      setNode(node);
    }
  }, []);

  if (!node) {
    return null;
  }

  return createPortal(<div className="overlay" />, node);
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="root">
      <div className="innerContainer">
        <div className="input" />
        <Overlay />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I would like this same effect, but (ideally) only using a CSS solution.


What about transform? transform: translateY(-100%)

Damn, that's literally one of the very few things I haven't tried... why does top: -100% not work? Can you please submit this as an answer, so I can mark it

After trying it out, unfortunately translateY(-45%) gets me the result I need, not 100%

I don't think CSS-only will work here, since CSS doesn't know about the portaled element's relationship to its parent.
I think I answered a similar question before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78076267/11572498 Check out the CodeSandbox in there

Took a look, the premise is quite different. At the moment, the path I decided to take was using top and right from getBoundingClientRect on the input div, and setting that inline as the value for top for my overlay div. Works, but seems hacky, I'd love some more input on the solution for this.

By the way, instead of using querySelector, you should either use a ref to pass down the element directly, or use useId to generate a unique element id for the current instance of the component.

Definitely, I could also omit the useEffect completely and coalesce the anchor node to document.body, I just wrote this out in a hurry on my phone

"After trying it out, unfortunately translateY(-45%) gets me the result I need, not 100%" - your current codesandbox appears to be using 100%, and the result looks to be the same, that top: -700px is giving ...? But either way, simply positioning the element from the bottom of the container, with the height of the container, should also do the trick - simply bottom: 100%
